# ¿Cómo compilar clases externas importadas en mi código usando javac?

Tags: java, javac

Quiero importar una clase que se encuentra en el paquete **src\models** en una clase que esta en un paquete externo a **src**, y cuando intento compilar la clase test de otras clases en cmd (No puedo usar ninguna IDE) obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: Imagen del cmd]

Sé que el problema esta en el import pero no se como importar en clases que están en paquetes externos de src como en la siguiente imagen, el proyecto esta de la siguiente manera:

[image: Arbol de archivos del proyecto]

---

Como tendria que importar para que no me de el error?

Codigo fuente de la clase test.TestCoin:

```java
package test;

import models.Coin;

public class TestCoin{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        double value = 12;
        double weight = 100;
        Coin coin = new Coin(value, weight);
        System.out.println("Valor: " + coin.getValue());
        System.out.println("Peso: " + coin.getWeight());
    }
}
```

---

Comment: No tendrías que añadir `src/models" en el `classpath`? (la opción `cp`).

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [tag:junit] para tus pruebas unitarias en vez de una clase con main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que el compilador es incapaz de hallar la ruta del paquete *models*, que no se encuentra dentro de la misma ruta de test, y por tanto, debes indicarla tu explícitamente.

El parámetro `-cp` o `-classpath` soporta múltiples rutas separadas por `;`, algo como:

```
javac -cp test;src -d test test\TestCoin.java
```